# MVC Routing Inside a Folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, routes, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have built a standard MVC application with controllers and views and the following routes:-

```
routes.MapRoute
(
  name: "PageNumber",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/page-{pageNumber}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "PageNumber" }
);
routes.MapRoute
(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Because this a back-end system, there will be a basic HTML website on the front of this. It means I need to route my site into a subfolder, so that the URL's look like this:-

```
SubFolder/Controller/Action/{id}
```

How can I do this, without changing all of my hard-coded links to include this sub-folder. I can't use `MVC` Areas for this, so was wondering if there was a way of changing the routing to automatically pre-pend the SubFolder bit of the URL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a new route:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Subfolder",
            url: "Subfolder/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

However you should not be hard coding links, if you have future plans to replace the basic HTML page you could use `@Html.ActionLink` to generate the anchor tags for you.

Comment: I'll try this and let you know where I get to! Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks. Changed my links to have `href="@Url.Action()">` because we have nested HTML inside the `<a></a>` links.